# Upload files to slack with files.upload method

Tags: c#, xaml, slack-api

I have created a feedback textbox where people can send feedbacks to my personal slack channel, using  slack Webhook URL,  now I'm trying to add a file upload button so users can upload images/files, using the Slack API token,  However, when I hit send the message is being sent successfully but no files are being uploaded to my channel.

I added a debugging and I actually receive back a successful response in the console

"File attachment payload created.
File uploaded successfully. Response: {"ok":true,"file":{"id":"F05MA6S1RPH","created":1692031941,"timestamp":1692031941,"name":"me-logo3.png","title":"me-logo3","mimetype":"image/png","filetype":"png","pretty_type":"PNG","user":"U05KZR8E40N","user_team":"T05KRT9Q44X","editable":false,"size":25673,"mode":"hosted","is_external":false,"external_type":"","is_public":false,"public_url_shared":false,"display_as_bot":false,"username":"","url_private":"https://files.slack.com......."

the "files:write" scope is enabled under

"OAuth & Permissions"

not sure what else to do

here is my code

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private byte[] attachFileBytes;
        private string attachFileName;


........more code......

 private  void AttachFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                attachFileName = openFileDialog.FileName; // Use 'FileName' instead of 'FileNames'
                attachFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(attachFileName);
            }
        }
        private async void SendFeedback_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string feedback = txtFeedback.Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(feedback))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your feedback before sending.");
                return;
            }


            string username = Environment.UserName;

            // Get the current date and time
            string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            string message = $"Feedback: {feedback}\nUsername: {username}\nDate and Time: {dateTime}";



          
           
            string slackWebhookUrl = "MY WEBHOOK URL";

            // Create the payload to send to Slack
            string payload = "{\"text\": \"" + message + "\"}";


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                await client.PostAsync(slackWebhookUrl, new StringContent(payload));


            }

            if (attachFileBytes != null)
            {
                // Create the payload for the file attachment
                MultipartFormDataContent fileContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                fileContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(attachFileBytes), "file", attachFileName);

                Console.WriteLine("File attachment payload created.");

                string slackApiToken = "API BOT TOKEN";

                // Upload the file to Slack using the Slack API
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", slackApiToken);
                    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://slack.com/api/files.upload", fileContent);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine($"File uploaded successfully. Response: {result}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to upload file. Error Response: {errorResponse}");
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Feedback sent successfully!");
            txtFeedback.Text = "";
            attachFileBytes = null;
            attachFileName = null;


            feedbackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            feedbackbutton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            // Show the "Open Feedback Box" button
            openFeedbackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        private void OpenFeedbackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Toggle visibility of feedback elements
            if (feedbackPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                feedbackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                feedbackbutton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                openFeedbackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                feedbackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                feedbackbutton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                openFeedbackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }


        }
```

```
<Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <!-- First row for the TextBlock -->
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <!-- Second row for the TextBox -->
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



                    <StackPanel x:Name="feedbackPanel" Margin="20,300,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed">

                        <TextBlock Text="Feedback:" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,270,0" />
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtFeedback" Height="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,185,0" Width="250" Grid.Row="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Padding="10" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" />
                            <Button x:Name="upload" Content="Attach File"  Margin="520,170,0,0" Width="100" Height="20" Click="AttachFileButton_Click" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Button x:Name="feedbackbutton" Content="Send Feedback" Click="SendFeedback_Click" Margin="0,10,185,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Width="250" Cursor="Hand" />

                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button x:Name="openFeedbackButton" Content="Open Feedback Box" Click="OpenFeedbackButton_Click" Margin="20,530,185,0" Cursor="Hand" Width="250" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </Grid>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where do you tell it which channel to use?

Comment: the webhook url is linked to my custom slack channel


Webhook URL 
https://hooks.slack.com/services/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

Channel 
#feedback

Added By
Moshe
Aug 3, 2023

Comment: Grasping at straws, I notice `"is_public": false` in the response.  Does that surprise you?

Comment: I see, how would I set it True?

Comment: I don't know.  There must be a parameter to the API that sets this.

Comment: I double-checked the API, and the files.upload method required for Bot Tokens, only "files.write" is what I have.  I don't see anything about is-public.....

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem, In the payload I wrote "channel" and in the fileCOntent I wrote "channels" (with an "s") by changing the payload to match up the fileContent solved the issue

string payload = "{"text": "" + message + "", "channels": "" + channelId + ""}";

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Send the message to Slack
            await client.PostAsync(slackWebhookUrl, new StringContent(payload));

            if (attachFileBytes != null)
            {
                // Create the payload for the file attachment
                MultipartFormDataContent fileContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                fileContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(attachFileBytes), "file", attachFileName);
                fileContent.Add(new StringContent(channelId), "channels");
```

it needs to be specifically "channels", per the docs